# How to set position while traversing through Treeview

Tags: c#

I want to traverse through a treeview & set the value property to be its position in the tree as shown below

```
     A[val:1]->A1[val:11]
        l l--->A2[val:12]
        l----->A3[val:13]

     B[val:2]->B1[val:21]
        l l--->B2[val:22]

     C[val:3]->C1[val:31]
        l l--->C2[val:32]
```

I have written a recursive which returns me all the nodes but i am unable to assign the desired position to its nodes.

```
  private void TraverseTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            TraverseTreeNode(node.ChildNodes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you only doing this for two level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that TreeNode.Value is of type string, this will, starting at level = 1:

```
    private static void TraverseTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int parentNumber)
    {
        var childNumber = 1;
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.Value = string.Format("{0}{1}", parentNumber, childNumber ).Substring(0,node.Depth+1);
            TraverseTreeNode(node.ChildNodes, parentNumber);
            childNumber++;
            if (node.Depth == 0) { parentNumber++; }
        }
    }
```

Only works for two levels but is easily extendable by adding additional parameters to TraverseTreeNode.

**UPDATE**

The following will work for any depth in hierarchy:

```
    private static void TraverseTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int parentNumber)
    {
        var childNumber = 1;
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.Value = node.Parent != null && node.Parent.Value != null
                ? string.Format("{0}{1}", node.Parent.Value, childNumber)
                : string.Format("{0}{1}", parentNumber, childNumber).Substring(0, node.Depth + 1);

            TraverseTreeNode(node.ChildNodes, parentNumber);
            childNumber++;
            if (node.Depth == 0) { parentNumber++; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you need recursive method, try this

```
     private void Caller()
    {
        TraverseTreeNode(treeView1.Nodes);
    }

    private void TraverseTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        int index = 1;
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.Text = (node.Parent != null ? node.Parent.Text : string.Empty) + index++;
            TraverseTreeNode(node.Nodes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It has to be recurssive